# Have a puppeteer generated PDF pass accessibility reports

Tags: pdf, puppeteer

I'm building PDFs using Puppeteer, the resulting PDF looks nice but it is failing PDF Accessibility reports.
The main issues have been the title of the PDF, and the Language of the PDF.
I have tried setting both via EXIF values (`Title`, `Language`), the title does display in certain cases but still fails Acrobat Pro's accessibility check report.
I have used another accessibility check report ( http://checkers.eiii.eu/en/pdfcheck/ ) and there the title is set successfully but not the language.

I have used `--export-tagged-pdf` as a launch parameter which fixed many other issues.

Would anyone have an idea how I could pass the accessibility report please? Mostly the language parameter. I'm using Node.js to generate the PDFs, even if there is another library to edit the PDF after the fact that would be really helpful, I wasn't able to figure that out.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I was able to satisfy Title and Language requirement by using additional `pdf-lib` package to modify existing pdf.

```pdfDoc.setLanguage("en-us");pdfDoc.setTitle("Some title");
```
Unfortunately i am not able to satisfy "bookmarks" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facing the same problem I managed to get all the required meta data and XMP data except PDF-UA identifier. I used the JS lib "pdf-lib" (https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfdocument) to set the meta data and exiftool-vendored to inject the XMP shema data.

```js
  const pdfLib = require('pdf-lib');
  const exiftool = require("exiftool-vendored").exiftool
  const fs = require('fs');
  const distexiftool = require('dist-exiftool');

  const pdfData = await fs.readFile('your-pdf-document.pdf');
  const pdfDoc = await pdfLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfData);

  const nowDate = new Date();
  const meta_creator = "The author";
  const meta_author = "The author";
  const meta_producer = "The producer";
  const meta_title = "Your PDF title";
  const meta_subject = "Your PDF subject";
  const meta_creadate = `${nowDate.getFullYear()}-${nowDate.getMonth()+1}-${nowDate.getDate()}`;
  const meta_keywords = ["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3", "keyword4"];

  // Implement PDF Title
  pdfDoc.setSubject(meta_subject);

  // Implement required "DisplayDocTitle" pdf var
  pdfDoc.setTitle(meta_title, {
    showInWindowTitleBar: true,
    updateMetadata: true
  });

  // Implement PDF language
  pdfDoc.setLanguage("en-EN");

  // Save file in order exiftool can load it
  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  await fs.promises.writeFile("your-pdf-document.pdf", pdfBytes);

  // We use "distexiftool" to get the TAGS from PDF/UA well formed XMP file "pdfUA-ID.xmp" and assign data to "your-pdf-document.pdf"
  execFile(distexiftool, ["-j","-xmp<=pdfUA-ID.xmp", "your-pdf-document.pdf"], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
        }
        afterTagsOperation()
    });

    async function afterTagsOperation(){
      // Open the file and write XMP tags with exiftool
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Author': meta_author });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Creator': meta_creator });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:CreateDate': meta_creadate });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Producer': meta_producer });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Title': meta_title });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Subject': meta_subject });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Keywords': meta_keywords });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Trapped': 'false' });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:DocumentID': `uuid:${nowDate.getTime()}` });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Title': meta_title });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Subject': meta_subject });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Keywords': meta_keywords });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Trapped': 'false' });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:Identifier': nowDate.getTime() });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp:PDFVersion': `v${nowDate.getTime()}` });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp-xmpMM:DocumentID': `uuid:${nowDate.getTime()}` });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp-dc:format': `application/pdf` });
      await exiftool.write("your-pdf-document.pdf", { 'xmp-dc:title': meta_title });

      // We save the file
      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      await fs.promises.writeFile("your-pdf-document.pdf", pdfBytes);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, I just edited my answer because I just found a way to get the PDF/UA missing identifier by assigning TAGS from compliance XMP file to the PDF file and then change some tags in order to customize the data.